# Нужна помощь с TabControl

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

Всех привествую, появился вопрос. Не могу при нажатии кнопки Clear не стираются позиции чексбоксов и текстовых полей. Чексбоксы и текстовые поля находятся в tabcontrol, которые завёрнуты в GroupBox. 
Вот мой код. Может лучше замесь  List использовать IEnumerable. Уже всю голову сломал, но так и ничего не выходит. Прошу вашей помощи.

```
private void clearBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.isDisabledCheckedChanged = true;
            foreach (Control control in GetChild<Control>(mainTabControl))
            {
                TextBox textBox;
                ComboBox comboBox;

                if ((checkBox = (control as CheckBox)) != null)
                {
                    checkBox.Checked = false;
                }
                else if ((textBox = (control as TextBox)) != null)
                {
                    if (!textBox.Name.Equals("toastMessageTBox"))
                    {
                        textBox.Text = "";
                        textBox.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else if ((comboBox = (control as ComboBox)) != null)
                {
                    comboBox.Enabled = false;
                }
            }

            this.progressTbox.Text = "";
            this.orderLv.Items.Clear();
            this.isDisabledCheckedChanged = false;
        }

        private static List<T> GetChild<T>(Control ctrl) where T : Control
        {
            List<T> tbs = new List<T>();
            foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
            {
                if (c is T)
                {
                    tbs.Add((T)c);
                }
            }
            return tbs;
        }
```

Comment: Сделайте функцию `GetChild` рекурсивной.

Comment: Извините, но не совсем понял Вас. Можете навести пример правленой функции.

Comment: Вместо `if ((checkBox = (control as CheckBox)) != null)` лучше `if (control is CheckBox)`

Comment: Controls возвращает только непосредственно дочерние элементы. Передавайте в GetChild groupbox, а не mainTabControl. Либо как писал Igor, сделайте рекурсивно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void GetChildren<T>(Control aParent, List<T> aList) where T : Control
{
  aList.AddRange(aParent.Controls.OfType<T>());
  foreach(Control c in aParent.Controls)
  {
    GetChildren<T>(c, aList);
  }
}

  List<CheckBox> checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>();
  GetChildren<CheckBox>(mainTabControl, checkboxes);
  checkboxes.ForEach(ch => ch.Checked = false);
  /*foreach (CheckBox ch in checkboxes)
  {
    ch.Checked = false;
  }*/
```

Comment: увы, но ошибка  получается. Вот https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q4ZAy6RUj4uzqz2k1Cq6NmXV2oZca9AQ

Comment: @MrIkso Я забыл поставить скобки после вызова: aList.AddRange(aParent.Controls.OfType<T> **()** );